# VM Not Booting XCP-NG failure could not read boot disk

Tags: xcp-ng

I have a server with a few VM's first VM's I setup using the main local storage which was an SSD. I then added a few HDD via RAID etc and thought it would be simple enough to add another storage device.

So f disk listed them fine, I then added the storage with below command:

xe sr-create content-type=user type=lvmohba device-config:device=/dev/sdc shared=false name-label="HDD6TB"

This shows up within Xcp-no center and can create a VM with the new disk however upon booting it just seems to throw error "boot device: CD-Rom medium detected - failure could not read boot disk" and then powers off.

Not sure if it is my storage or anything but have tried on a few disks and have the same issue. These vary from vdisks to standalone disks in raid controller to a HDD plugged directly in Mobo so feel it must be something I’m doing wrong with formatting / partitioning of these new disks.

Also tried Changing boot order and restarted a few times unplugged etc. Recreated partitions a few separate ways but one thing I noticed is even though they are ext4 I cant go above 2tb.

So no luck on adding any extra drives other than the one it was originally installed on, what am i doing wrong here?